# a pointer about *argv[]

Tags: c, pointers, gdb, arguments, program-entry-point

This is my `main.c`

```
......
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    init_arg(&argc, &argv);
    ......
}
```

This is my `init_arg.c`

```
......
void init_arg(int *argc, char ***argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", *argv[1]);
    ......
}
```

I compiler it with no error and warning.

I run it:

`./a.out include`

It get **Segmentation fault**

When I debug it， I found step  `printf("%s\n", *argv[1]);`

get wrong, It show:

`print *argv[1]`

`Cannot access memory at address 0x300402bfd`

I want to know, How to print `argv[1]` in `init_arg()` function.

Comment: +1 for debugging first and including it in your post!

Comment: In GDB when your code crashes run the command bt to see the stack trace leading up to your crash. Read http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html for example C program code that handles program arguments.

Comment: here's a snippet with examples [http://pastebin.com/SVAZjsXA](http://pastebin.com/SVAZjsXA)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add a pair of parentheses around (*argv) to change the order of evaluation. The way you currently have it, the [1] is evaluated first, yielding an invalid pointer, which then gets dereferenced, causing undefined behavior.

```
printf("%s\n", (*argv)[1]);
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, you can use `argv[0][1]` (just as long to type, but perhaps slightly more readable).

Comment: @torek I would refrain from using `argv[0]` in place of `(*argv)`, because what's passed in is a "scalar" pointer (i.e a pointer to a single array), rather than an array of pointers to arrays. I think that the `(*argv)` syntax underscores the notion that we're looking at a pointer to a scalar.

Comment: apparently you fall into the group of people who like to maintain a distinction that C drops.  I sympathize!  In the early 1980s, I had a colleague who liked to mix pointer and array notation all the time depending on what was convenient.  In particular he'd do things like: `time_t now[1]; time(now); ...` instead of `time_t now; time(&now); ...`. :-)

Comment: "[...] maintain a distinction that C drops" That's a common misconception driven primarily by arrays decaying into pointers when passed into functions. The example that you show is a good and perfectly legitimate one: there is a big difference between treating an array of one item as a pointer and treating a pointer as an array of one item.

Comment: My point is that the *C language* does not provide any way (in the callee, e.g., function `fn`) to discover whether some pointer argument `T *p` points to a single item (`T var; fn(&var);`) or to the first of `N` sequential items (`T var[N]; fn(var);`).  It helps *programmers* to distinguish them, but the language itself does not do that for you.  Compare with, e.g., Pascal and Go, which do.

Comment: @torek, are you Chris Torek?  If so, stackoverflow became very interesting for me.  Love your posts on clc.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alok: Yes ... I still have access to use(less)net news, but it's mostly too painful these days, with all the spam. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Argv is already a pointer. Just pass it like this:

```
init_arg(&argc, argv);
```

And init_arg should look like this:

```
void init_arg(int *argc, char **argv) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but then he could also just pass `argc` rather than `&argc`.  Presumably the point to passing both `&argc` and `&argv` is to allow `init_arg` to modify them.

Comment: You can modify them both like this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the reason for passing `&argc` and `&argv` in the first place is so that you can update them inside `init_arg`.  Here's how I prefer to write such functions, in general:

```
/*
 * init_arg: do something useful with argc and argv, and update argc and argv
 * before returning so that the caller can do something else useful that's
 * not shared with all the other callers of init_arg().
 * (this comment of course needs updating to describe the useful things)
 */
void init_arg(int *argc0, char ***argv0) {
    int argc = *argc0;
    char **argv = *argv0;
    ... all the operative code goes here, and then ...
    *argc0 = argc;
    *argv0 = argv;
}
```

Of course this means you must not do early `return`s inside `init_arg`, so there are some tradeoffs, but it sure is a lot easier to work with the same regular old `argc` and `argv` inside `init_arg`.

Comment: Just use a goto if you miss the early return :)